# Extract xml data using xmlSApply in R

Tags: xml, r

I try to extract the zipcodes from the xml file in the URL below (see code).

```
fileurl <- "http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml"
doc <- xmlTreeParse(fileurl)
root <- xmlRoot(doc)
xmlName(root)
xmlSApply(root, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
```

However, I do not seem able to get the zip codes out and put them into a data frame.

Comment: Where in your existing code are you extracting the `<zipcode>` tag values?

Comment: The last line. I also tried `xmlSApply(root, "//zipcode", xmlValue), but this gave an error.`